# Should plural form or singular form of the verb be used in the following sentence?

Tags: grammar

> In order to serve you better, the Board of Directors **is** delighted to
>   officially announce the launch of our LinkedIn page.

vs

> In order to serve you better, the Board of Directors **are** delighted to
>   officially announce the launch of our LinkedIn page.

Answer (score 1):

"Is" is the correct word to use.

Both "is" and "are" are conjugations of the (very) irregular verb "be", specifically they are the 3rd person singular and 3rd person plural present tense forms, respectively.

The subject of the sentence is the noun phrase "Board of Directors" which is a single entity, even though it is comprised of multiple people, in the same way one can have a single corporation or government make an announcement, despite those being comprised of multiple people.

Answer (score 0):

In American English, a "Board of Directors", a team or a group is considered singular. In British English, they are considered plural.

Comment: what are your grounds for suggesting that the matter is so clear? As an editor in an organisation reporting on the performance of boards, I found that it was a matter of endless controversy as to whether to use singular or plural for bodies comprising individual persons.